# Alphabetically sorting List in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I have a question related to the following code(tried to find it on the internet but couldn't). If I want to sort a List of Employee objects by their name in Java can I use the following approach?(found other approaches too but I'm interested in this one).

```java
    public class SortByName implements Comparator<Employee> {
        public int compare(Employee e1,Employee e2) {
            return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
        }
    }
```

and somewhere in my main method the array of employees being empList, I could have:

Collections.sort(empList,new SortByName());

? 
New to Java sorry if this is a stupid question..

Comment: Did you try compiling and running the code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a canonical example of sorting by comparator:

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    ...
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    ...
}
List<Employee> employees = ...
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName));
System.out.println(employees); //prints out sorted list
```

In response to your query about your approach: yes, it's a valid approach. It compiles and runs correctly. However, it's generally used for cases where you have a very complex Comparator and feel the need to separate such logic into another class.